# How can I insert a line at the beginning of a file with Perl's Tie::File?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to insert/add a line 'COMMENT DUMMY' at the beginnig of a file as a first row if /PATTERN/ not found.
I know how to do this with OPEN CLOSE function. Probably after reading the file it should look something like this:

```
open F, ">", $fn or die "could not open file: $!"; ;
     print F "COMMENT DUMMY\n", @array;
close F;
```

But I have a need to implement this with the use of the Tie::File function and don't know how.

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 
use Tie::File;


my $fn = 'test.txt';
tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', $fn or die "could not tie file: $!";

untie @lines;
```

Comment: You may want to consider shifting away from using Tie::File.

Comment: @Ether any particular reason? Its quite efficient at doing a bunch of file manipulations that are traditionally done poorly by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unshift` works:

```
use Tie::File;
my $fn = 'test.txt';
tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', $fn or die "could not tie file: $!";
unshift @lines, "COMMENT DUMMY\n";
untie @lines;
```

Comment: It's working but I need a little more assistance because the code adds 'COMMENT DUMMY' after each processing regardless of /PATTERN/. I added this but it's not working. What I'm doing wrong. 
    
    if (my $lines !~ /PATTERN/) {
    unshift @lines, "COMMENT DUMMY\n";
    }

Comment: How about trying to do that yourself? Hint: wrap the `unshift` in an `if` block. Come back and ask again if you get stuck.

Comment: @thebourneid there's no such thing as `$lines`, and declaring it in the if isn't going to get you anywhere except to let you fail a regex match against undef without `strict vars` complaining :)

Comment: sorry for the bothering. I wrapped themn already but will find the answer myself.
thanks

Comment: @Kinopiko : The OP specifically requested to add the line if the file contains `/PATTERN/`. It's not like he came back with the requirement afterwards. Why are you playing hardball?

Comment: Kinopiko, I didn't mean to play hardball. I realized that instead of making hasty and stupid comments I should try to find the answer myself after you pointed me to the right direction and that is what I did. That's all.
Thanks again for your help, and I really mean it.

Answer (score 1):

[Kinopiko's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886290/insert-a-line-at-the-beginning-of-a-file/2886300#2886300) pointed you in the right direction. To complete your need, I'd do the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::File;

my $fileName = 'test.txt';

tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', $fileName or die "Unable to tie $fileName: $!";

unshift @lines, "DUMMY COMMENT\n" if grep { /PATTERN/ } @lines;

untie @lines;
```

#### Explanation

- You may already know that although the `if` statement comes after the `unshift` statement in writing, it gets evaluated first.
- When you see [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html), think of it as a list filter. Basically, it takes your `@lines` list and uses it to create a new list with just elements that match `/PATTERN/`.
- The `if` statement evaluates to true if the new, filtered list contains any elements, and false if the list is empty. Based on this, the `"DUMMY COMMENT\n"` line is added to your `@lines` list.

Answer (score 1):

The point of tie is to make one thing behave like another. Since you are tie-ing a file to an array, it now acts like an array. You use array operators to do whatever you need to do.